# Playback in camera view is flickering

Tags: game-engine, camera

I'm having trouble finding an answer to this, as all my searches come up with people suggesting ways to make a camera shudder effect!

My problem is that in Blender Game mode, when I switch to camera view and play the game, the background outside of the camera view jitters/ flickers very fast.

If I start the game in user/ortho view, it doesn't happen, and when I move to the next level, the camera view is perfect.  It's only when I start the game in camera view.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Is this a known problem?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds strange. Does that always happen (with any file)? If not can you post a demo file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, it happens with any file.  Here is a link to a screen grab showing the problem.  In User view it doesn't happen if I hit P.  In camera view it happens if I hit P and when I hit embedded player button.  The player button also goes crazy in both views.  See for yourself here: [link](https://d.pr/l7BD1U)

Comment: By the way, I meant to include this information: I'm on version 2.79 on Mac OS 10.12.6.  Also just tested again and it does keep on happening on subsequent levels.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a mac issue - the solution is to change the Window Draw Method in User Preferences/System - from no multisample to Multisample 2 at least.
[image: multisample setting]